# How to modify the UI in apex:pageblocktable format

Tags: visualforce

I have a vf page as below. I want to convert the UI as below

Current UI -

[image]

I want to show it as below -

[image]

VF Page -

```
<apex:page standardController="Custom_Package__c" extensions="ContactController">
    <apex:form >
    <apex:pageMessages />
    <apex:pageBlock >
        <apex:pageBlockSection id="addressData" columns="6">

            <apex:inputtext value="{!S}">
                <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!fetchRelatedAccountData}" rerender="addressData" />
            </apex:inputtext>
   <!--         <apex:actionStatus id="requestStatus" startText="(requesting...)"  stopText=" (done)"/>  -->

            <apex:inputField value="{!c.Market__c}"/>

            <apex:inputField value="{!c.State__c}" />

            <apex:inputField value="{!c.Circulation__c}" />

            <apex:inputField value="{!c.First_Issue__c}" />

            <apex:inputField value="{!c.Last_Issue__c}" />

            <apex:inputField value="{!c.Per_Unit_Open_Rate__c}" />

            <apex:inputField value="{!c.Space_Discount__c}" />

            <apex:inputField value="{!c.Space_Unit__c}" />

       </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Apex Class -

```
    public class ContactController{
    public Custom_Package__c c {get;set;}
    private Custom_Package__c  acc {get;set;}
    public string S {get;set;}
    public list<Custom_Package__c> listAccount{ get; set; }

    public ContactController(ApexPages.StandardController ctrl){
        c = (Custom_Package__c) ctrl.getRecord();
        // make sure all required fields are filled in or the request won't work
    }

    Public void addAccount()
    {
        Custom_Package__c acc = new Custom_Package__c();
        listAccount.add(acc);

    }

    public void fetchRelatedAccountData(){
    system.debug('@@@@' + S);

            acc = [SELECT Name, Market__c, State__c,Circulation__c,First_Issue__c,Last_Issue__c,Per_Unit_Open_Rate__c,Space_Discount__c,Space_Unit__c FROM Custom_Package__c WHERE Name = :S];
            c.Market__c= acc.Market__c;
            c.State__c= acc.State__c;
            c.Circulation__c= acc.Circulation__c;
            c.First_Issue__c= acc.First_Issue__c;
            c.Last_Issue__c= acc.Last_Issue__c;
            c.Per_Unit_Open_Rate__c= acc.Per_Unit_Open_Rate__c;
            c.Space_Discount__c= acc.Space_Discount__c;
            c.Space_Unit__c = acc.Space_Unit__c ;
            system.debug('@@@@' + acc);

    }
}
```

Comment: you are looking for multiple values but you have single object on vf page? pageblocktable is the solution of your problem but it would be great if you can update your question with more details. here is the link for page block table

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_pageBlockTable.htm

Comment: Start with using an apex:pageblockTable instead of just a plain page block??? Maybe??

Comment: If i am using page block, how can i use action:support and autopopulate fields with values. Please help